# Initialize an object in another class constructor with arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino

I am creating some project in Arduino.
And, I am stuck with following problem.

There is a class B in header file `B.h`

```
class B {
  private:
    int n;
  public:
    B(int);
    init();
}
```

Then, there is a class A in header file `A.h`

```
class A {
  private:
    B b;
  public:
    A();
    init();
}
```

And, here is the `Class A` constructor definition in file `A.cpp`

```
#include <B.h>
A::A() {
  b(3);
}
```

Which is giving me error

```
../A.cpp: In constructor 'A::A()':
../A.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to 'B::B()'
note: candidates are: B::B(int)
```

I guess, this is because I haven't defined a default constructor (with no argument) in `class B`.

But, haven't I initializing object b in `class A` constructor with argument 3?

Then, why is the compiler still going for the default constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to init the member **before** the constructor.
b member constructor must be called before the A. therefore you call it outside the member.

Change class A constructor to this:

```
#include <B.h>
A::A():b(3) {
}
```

**EDIT**

if you don't call the initialization, the default constructor been called. but B class don't have default constructor, that is why you got error.

Comment: Wow, this worked. But explain what kind of statement is this? And, how it is working. I've never come across statement like this.

Comment: So, does this statement have any name? What would you call it?

Comment: I think it called member initialization.

Comment: Oh, I've got the right word "Member initialization list". http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html